# Does lstlisting support Rust?

Tags: listings

When I define the Rust language in TeX Live 2023’s `lstlisting` like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Rust]
let config_redis_string: String = env::var("REDIS_URL").expect("redis url missing");
\end{lstlisting}
```

it does not seem to support the [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) language. Is it possible to add support for `Rust`?

Comment: For adding new languages see section 3.2 and 4.7 of the manual. For getting a new feature within the package, ask the package author. As an alternative try [package `minted`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted), because Rust is one of the [supported languages of pygments](https://pygments.org/languages/).

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Always make a small test document which includes a class and the necessary packages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the style from https://github.com/denki/listings-rust , the following seems to work fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings, listings-rust}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Rust]
let config_redis_string: String = env::var("REDIS_URL").expect("redis url missing");
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you add this on mac? which do you still the sty file where mactex can see it?

Comment: @MichaelKMadison As a quick solution, you could place the `.sty` file in the same folder as your .tex file. Alternatively, you could place it somewhere where latex can find it, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/36296 for instructions.

Comment: thanks very much

Comment: @MichaelKMadison You're welcome!